# I could never have dreamed of a better vacation

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider this sentence, please:

*Last night I dreamed of a wonderful vacation. I **could never have dreamed** of a better vacation!*

Is the second sentence talking about my inability to dream of a better vacation **only in the past** or is it talking about my inability to dream **at any time**?

Can I use the following sentence to talk about my **future inability**?

*I **could never dream** of a better vacation*.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes** to both questions, however I would modify the usage slightly.

This definitively indicates the past:

> I couldn't have dreamed of a better vacation!

This can indicate the present or the future:

> I couldn't dream of a better vacation!

Answer (score 0):

*Can I use the following sentence to talk about my future inability?*

- Yes

*Is the second sentence talking about my inability to dream of a better vacation only in the past or is it talking about my inability to dream at any time?*

- in the past

#### Reason

- There **was** a time when X could **never** **have** **kept** me spellbound. (Hypothetical - X didn't try to keep me spellbound but would not have been able to)
- There was a time when X could **never** **keep** me spellbound. (There were times when X tried to keep me spellbound but failed.)

Example [Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/could-never-have-done-vs-could-never-do.3428747/)

Answer (score -1):

The correct use = I never would have dreamed of a better vacation.

I could never dream = referring to your past ability or lack thereof.